# Media Browser show the directory but it doesn't show content in MODX

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I have been encountering the following issue and I´m going a bit crazy. I hope you can help me:

1. In the backoffice, I can see the media folders but when I click on it, it doesn´t show me the content (files)
2. The strange thing is that this is only happening in some folders. And there are no restrictions or rules applied ont he media browser.

Some things to take in to consideration:

1. Modx version 2.3 (I already upgraded, but still not working)
2. Ftp folder permissions are all 777
3. The media Path file source are all correct
4. I deleted the cache + permissions
5. The error.log file isn´t showing any visible error.
6. My ACL is correct, it has administrator permissions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7tHY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGDeo.png)

Please advice.
Many thanks!!

UPDATE : 

*The directories was corrupted  I created the new directories and rename the old directories.*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix your particular issue - but I noticed in the media source setup you have a forward slash (/) before your paths as well as after. I think in general it's good practice to have the same number of forward slashes as you have directories listed. I usually include the / after the last directory, but DON'T include one before "assets".

I don't know if this is the "official" way to do things, but I have had many issues uploading and using the media browser if I don't set it up as above.

Comment: Trank , I don't think because the same is all media sources and some do not work, the configuration is same in media sources 

https://postimg.org/image/9temrrzw1/

I don't find solution the other posibility is create the new directory but isn't correct